# Continuous rotation of image array

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to find some jQuery lib. for continuous rotation of image array? In my case I have about 30 images (partner logos) and I want to set them in some jquery lib or plain css code where images will rotate continuous. Images and information will be imported via ajax query. Vision example:
[image]

It could look like this, or be in one line same height line.

Appreciate any help and suggestions for further investigation.

Comment: You are mentioning bootstrap... like a carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of plugins for that purpose. Here an example with **slick** (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/). 
Most carousels/sliders have an option for continous rotation. Just google for slider and fill it with ajax before initialization.

Mind that SO is not a platform for recommendations.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 7,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 6,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
      }
    }
  ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/40/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/50/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/60/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/70/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/80/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/90/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/100/100"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/110/100/100"></div>
</div>
```